# How to open data tags url in new tab with Html

Tags: html

I have this html code

```html
<div
  class="store-badge"
  data-name="Cheerswipe"
  data-google-play-url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.puyou.cheerswipe"
  data-app-store-url="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cheerswipe/id1468158095?ls=1"
></div>
<script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/store-badge@1/build/bundle.js"></script>
```

And i want to open the url it containt in a new tab ,

Do somebody can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript (check codepen for result)

https://codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/gORaPYq

for add _blank after add a tag im remove async from your script tag

```html
<div
 class="store-badge"
 data-name="Cheerswipe"
 data-google-play-url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.puyou.cheerswipe"
 data-app-store-url="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cheerswipe/id1468158095?ls=1"
></div>
<script  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/store-badge@1/build/bundle.js"></script>
<script>
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var len = links.length;

for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
{
   links[i].target = "_blank";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `target='_blank'` in your linked tags

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved Just Using Pure JavaScript

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].target = "_blank";
}
```

```html
<div
 class="store-badge"
 data-name="Cheerswipe"
 data-google-play-url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.puyou.cheerswipe"
 data-app-store-url="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cheerswipe/id1468158095?ls=1"
></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/store-badge@1/build/bundle.js"></script>
```

Or you Can Use JQquery

```js
$('.store-badge').find('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("target", "_blank"));
});
```

```html
<div
    class="store-badge"
    data-name="Cheerswipe"
    data-google-play-url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.puyou.cheerswipe"
    data-app-store-url="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cheerswipe/id1468158095?ls=1"
></div>

<script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/store-badge@1/build/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After opening a [issue](https://github.com/apuyou/store-badge/issues/20) in the github repo of the package you are using, the Developer has updated his code (version 1.3.0).

Now you can simply use the property `data-target="_blank"` to open the link in a new tab!

Example:

```html
<p>Download Cheerswipe now!</p>
<div
  class="store-badge"
  data-name="Cheerswipe"
  data-google-play-url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.puyou.cheerswipe"
  data-app-store-url="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cheerswipe/id1468158095?ls=1"
  data-target="_blank"
></div>
<script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/store-badge@1/build/bundle.js"></script>
```